# Is there an easy way for collision detection of html and/or svg elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a number of labels acting as an axis for a chart. This labels can quickly overlap when the numbers get big. I need to find a solution to handle this collisions. Could be hiding some of the labels or cutting all of them or placing them differently.

So the question is: Is there an easy way for collision detection of html and/or svg elements? I don't care if the solution is CSS or JavaScript (jQuery and d3.js are already involved). Any solution is welcome!

Comment: You can get the bounding box of elements (at least in SVG anyway), so you could do some basic rectangle collision detection if needed.